# Can you download installs for windows phones?

Tags: storage

I have apps that I use a lot games mostly.

I'm concerned if Microsoft drops support for my phone I won't have a way to install such applications.

Is there a way to download the installers maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now,
No, there's no way to download Installers and Install the app from Installers(*.appx)

> I'm concerned if Microsoft drops support for my phone I won't have a way to install such applications.

As we heard rumors, Microsoft is about to launch Surface phone, so there's no way Microsoft is dropping support for Windows 10 Mobile, at least for couple of years.

**Links:**
[Windows Central and Build 2017](http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-needs-talk-about-phones)
[Windows Phone isn't dead - Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-still-isnt-dead-heres-why)
[Surface Phone - Windows Central](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/microsoft-surface-mobile-phone-news/)